# How do I delete an item from a ListView in Android? Are there built-in controls like iOS has?

Tags: java, android, ios, eclipse, android-listview

iOS has an easy-to-add Edit button that attaches to a UITableView to allow for a quick and easy way to delete items. See the screenshots here:

[image]

[image]

Is there anything built-in like this for Android (specifically 4.0 and higher) so I don't have to create my own custom deleting controls and code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would indeed be nice to have. Unfortunately does Android not have that built-in. You need to add that yourself.